# При повторном запросе на тот же url происходит задержка

Tags: express, react-native, fetch

Эта функция отправляет запросы на сервер в моём приложении React Native.

```
async function request(url, method = 'GET', data, contentType = 'application/json') {
  const state = store.getState()
  const config = {
    method,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': state.user.token
    }
  }
  if (contentType === 'application/json') config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

  if (method === 'POST' || method === 'PATCH') {
    config.body = data
  }
  console.log(url, new Date())
  const response = await fetch(url, config)
  return await response.json()
}
```

Сервер на express. Пример роута с контроллером.

```
router.get('/message/:userID', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), controller.getAllMessage)
```

```
module.exports.getAllMessage = async function(req, res) {   
    try {
      console.log('getAllMessage', new Date())
      //какой-то код
      res.status(200).json(message)
      
    } catch (e) {
      errorHandler(res, e)
    }
  }
```

В этом примере если я отправляю запрос первый раз, разница по времени между логам минимальна, а если запрос идёт второй и далее раз на тот же url, либо url, который отличается `:userID` от того, что уже был, задержка составляет неопределённое количество секунд, в среднем 15-30. С другими роутами тоже самое. В Postman и в веб-клиенте на Angular все запросы идут без задержек. Не уверена, в чём здесь поблема. Любая помощь будет выско оценена.

Если вы слитаете, что проблема не в приведённом коде, вы можете посмотреть полный код.

Сервер: https://github.com/ZRomanova/emo_new

Клиент: https://github.com/ZRomanova/emo_mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась из-за socket.io. Строка `const socket = io.connect(url)` оказалась внутри функции компонента. Я поместила её до компонента и проблема ушла.